# Maximizing an integral over a convex region

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, inequalities, convex-geometry, global-optimization, convex-optimization

Let $C$ denote a compact, convex region in the plane containing the origin with unit area, and let $f$ be a probability distribution on $C$.  Let $f^\ast$ denote the distribution that maximizes the quantity $$\mathcal{G}(f):=\iint_C a\sqrt{f(x)} + b\|x\|f(x)~dx $$ where $a$ and $b$ are given constants.  I'm interested in bounding $\mathcal{G}(f^\ast)$ from above.  Clearly, we know that $\mathcal{G}(f^\ast)\leq a + b\max_{x\in C} \|x\|$ because we have $\iint_C \sqrt{f(x)}\leq 1~dx$ and $\iint_C \|x\|f(x)~dx\leq \max_{x\in C} \|x\|$.  Are there any tighter upper bounds for this expression?

Comment: You should be able to solve for $f^*$ directly. Let $f(x)=g(x)^2$, then you have the following stationarity condition: $a + 2(b||x|| -\mu) g(x)=0$, where $\mu$ is a Lagrange multiplier. So you just have to solve for the $\mu$ that gives $\int_C g(x)^2=1$.